# How to serve source folder on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

The below app.yaml pasted below gives error:

> sre_constants.error: cannot refer to open group

```
application: villagegamedev
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes


handlers:
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: ./\1
  upload: ./\1
```

My express purpose for this test is to serve the source folder.  When I Google this effort, the search only comes up with all the docs that say "App Engine does not serve files directly out of your application's source directory unless configured to do so." So how do I configure it to do so?

Answer (score 0):

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_dir: static
```

Then just put all of the files you want to serve in a directory named `static`.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website) gives a full description.

Basically what you should do is;

1. Create a project on google cloud platform
2. Create a directory on your computer with the same name as the
   project created above. Create your app.yaml file here.
3. Paste this code into the app.yaml file

   ```
   runtime: python27
   api_version: 1
   threadsafe: true

   handlers:
   - url: /
   static_files: www/index.html
   upload: www/index.html

   - url: /(.*)
   static_files: www/\1
   upload: www/(.*)
   ```
4. Install the google sdk into this folder (browse and select this
   folder when prompted during installation).
5. Create a directory named www in your project folder. Save your static website files here.
6. Start up the google cloud sdk on your computer and run the following command

   ```
   gcloud app deploy
   ```

   7.run `gcloud app browse` to see your website in your browser.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You and Amber have offered some useful alternatives to serving the source folder, but what I'm looking for is how to actually serve the source folder, I want type in mysite.appspot.com/app.yaml and see the actual file served up.